# Powershell: getting computer architecture if computer is offline

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

I have come across the below line that allows to identify if a computer is 32-bit or 64-bit:

> $(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Processor -ComputerName
>   [name]).AddressWidth

It works well if a computer is online. However, I need to be able to get architecture information even if machine is offline (turned off or not connected to the company's network at the moment).

Is it possible to get this information for an offline computer using another cmdlet (e. g. get-qadobject / get-qadcomputer)?
I was trying

> get-qadcomputer [name] | fl

but was unable to find architecture. Is it not recorded by Active Roles at all or just not showing among default properties?

Comment: There is no script or command you can run to get information from a machine that is turned off

Answer (score 0):

If your target machine is offline - then you can't connect to it to get information... the same as you can't speak someone when their phone is turned off.

I am guessing that this has been asked because you get a horrible looking error when trying this against multiple machines and not all are on.  The best way to get around this is to use a try catch block:

```
try {
    $a = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Processor -ComputerName $computerName).AddressWidth
} catch {
    Write-Host "Computer Offline: $ComputerName"
}
```